# tkinter unrecognized selector error

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting the following error when trying to use Tkinter:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f80e70137e0'
```

I am using it within a class in the code below:

```
from Tkinter import *


class Interface():

    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()

        w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
        w.pack()
        root.mainloop()
```

The code is being called in a separate file using the following code:

```
from Interface import *
Interface()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you looked that [python's warnings about tcl on OSX](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/)?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you searched for other questions and answers with the phrase "NSInvalidArgumentException"?